# Como inserir vários arrays ao mesmo tempo no banco de dados?

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

Tenho uma tabela e cada linha tem 6 inputs que devem ser salvos no banco de dados como um produto.

O sistema tem um botão no HTML, que adiciona mais uma linha com 6 inputs, ou seja, ao clicar em `submit` preciso salvar uma quantidade indeterminada de formulários de uma vez pro banco de dados.

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="celula">
        <input type="text" name="descricao[]" required>
    </div>
    <div class="celula">
        <input type="text" name="tamanho[]" required>
    </div>
    <div class="celula">
        <input type="text" name="cor[]" required>
    </div>
    <div class="celula">
        <input type="number" name="qtde[]" required>
    </div>
    <div class="celula">
        <input type="text" name="pagamento[]" required>
    </div>
    <div class="celula">
        <input type="number" name="valor[]" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Utilizei `array_map` para separar os valores do jeito que eu preciso e ele me retornou os arrays corretamente, agora o problema é que não consigo salvar todos os arrays, sempre salva apenas o primeiro.

```
if(isset($_POST['descricao']) && !empty($_POST['descricao'])) {

    $descricao = $_POST['descricao']; //array
    $tamanho = $_POST['tamanho']; //array
    $cor = $_POST['cor']; //array
    $qtde = $_POST['qtde']; //array
    $pagamento = $_POST['pagamento']; // array - forma de pagamento
    $valor = $_POST['valor']; //array


    $compra = array_map(null,$descricao,$tamanho,$cor,$qtde,$pagamento,$valor);

    $adicionar = $venda->adicionar($compra);
    print_r($compra);
}
```

Mandei tudo pra função adicionar que vai inserir os produtos no banco, dei um `print_r` em `$compra`  pra fazer um teste com produtos 'w' e 'Q' eu queria dar 
preciso saber como salvá-los:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
            [1] => WWWWWWWWWWWW
            [2] => WWWWWWW
            [3] => 10
            [4] => WWWW
            [5] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ  //descricao
            [1] => QQQQQQQQQQQQQQ  //tamanho
            [2] => QQQQQQQ  //cor
            [3] => 20  //quantidade
            [4] => QQQQQQQQ //forma de pagamento
            [5] => 200  //valor
        )
)
```

Comment: Caso alguma resposta resolva sua dificuldade, considere marcar a resposta como aceita, veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Para fazer isso, forneça uma lista de valores entre parêntesis para cada registro e separe as listas com virgulas.

Use o foreach para gerar a variável `$values` que irá servir de VALUE da declaração INSERT

```
$compra = array_map(null,$descricao,$tamanho,$cor,$qtde,$pagamento,$valor);

$i=0;
foreach($compra AS $indice => $val) {
  $values .= " ('$descricao[$i]', '$tamanho[$i]', '$cor[$i]', '$qtde[$i]', '$pagamento[$i]', '$valor[$i]' ),";
  $i++;
}
//RETIRA A ULTIMA VIRGULA
$values=substr($values, 0, -1);

echo "INSERT ..... VALUES $values";
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado pela ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 1):

A inserção tem que ser feita uma por vez.
   Faz um

```
foreach($compra as $compras){
    //comando que adicionará no banco

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu coloquei o foreach, mas da forma que eu fiz só está salvando  o primeiro array.

```
function adicionar($compra){

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $data = date('Y-m-d H:i');

        foreach($compra as $compras){                   
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `vendas` (`descricao`, `tamanho`, `cor`,`qtde`,`pagamento`,`valor`, `data`) VALUES (:descricao, :tamanho, :cor, :qtde, :pagamento, :valor, :data)";

            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(':descricao', $compras[0]);
            $sql->bindValue(':tamanho', $compras[1]);
            $sql->bindValue(':cor', $compras[2]);
            $sql->bindValue(':qtde', $compras[3]);
            $sql->bindValue(':pagamento', $compras[4]);
            $sql->bindValue(':valor', $compras[5]);
            $sql->bindValue(':data', $data);
            $sql->execute();

            return true;
    }
}
```